# How do I change the template of an existing media item from unversioned to versioned in Sitecore?

Tags: templates, sitecore, media, sitecore8.2

## Sitecore 8.2

A great many media items have been uploaded as "unversioned" template
    `/sitecore/templates/System/Media/unversioned/Jpeg`.

This needs to be the "versioned" template
`/sitecore/templates/System/Media/Versioned/Jpeg`.

If I use the Content Editor to *"Configure -> Change"* and select the template that I want. I get the report. *"Some data might be lost"* (Field "out of date") then the service hangs, and eventually restarts.

Is this a known issue?
Is there a better way to accomplish this?

Comment: Do you have a custom field "out of date" on it? possible an custom event, pipeline processor do somethings with the for me unknown field "out of date" what causes the hangs, But can you check the log file.

Comment: I don't have access to the log file. I believe believe that Field belongs to cloud words.

Comment: You can do it programmatically with item.ChangeTemplate(template); but your approach is a good one. perhaps it is an option to package the media and try to reproduce on development with access to the log files.

Comment: This issue is just the begining of the issue evidently, if the sitecore template is versioned/pdf, when the pdf is opened in a new tab with "target="_blank", the PDF open 1 time for every language version in the sitecore instance. This seems a pretty significant bug.

Comment: This is still an issue in Sitecore 9.3 !